# Which statistical test to apply?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, spss, biostatistics, psychology

I'm trying to find out which delivery time is the best to give out instructions, my data consists of 3 conditions (1st, receive instructions at the beginning) (2nd, receive instructions halfway through the task) (3rd, receive instructions towards the end). My dependant variable is measures of both correct and incorrect scores from all conditions. My data is not normally distributed and therefore I was wondering whether I should use MANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis test to answer my research question.

Comment: How about turning your response variable into the rate of correct answers (proportion of correct scores), there is only a single response variable then no need for "multivariate ANOVA".

Comment: I haven't thought of that! thanks, thats great help, do u know if I could do that on SPSS?

Comment: Yes: this analysis can be done in SPSS. You'll first need to code a new variable to create the proportion of correct sources, and then you'll just use that new variable as the dependent variable in a univariate ANOVA (or Kruskal-Wallis test if your data are not appropriate for parametric methods)

Comment: Why would you use ANOVA on count proportions?